# WSO2 Data Mapper Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to use the mapping technique with the dynamic input/output?. Because WSO2 documentation shows only the input/output from the file system.

Basically I would like to map output of one webserive as input of the other webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by writing the custom sequence and use as a mediator in the WSO2 ESB service creation. No straight forward way yet

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the schema of the output and the expected schema for the input, this can be done. [1] provides a sample where an output from a web service is written to a csv file using the data mapper. In a similar manner if the schema is known of the input and the output your requirement can be achieved.

[1] http://chathurikaerandi.blogspot.com/2016/07/mapping-to-csv-and-writing-output-to.html

Thanks
Erandi

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But it would be tedious job. I was expecting something from WSO2 ESB out the box like what you have in IBM Process server Data Objects